# How do you make buns hollow inside for filling?

Tags: baking, bread, filling

Chinese and Korean filled buns are my family's favorite. I've succeeded in making soft breads but never know how to make the buns hollow to inject a cream inside. I know that some recipes simply put the filling inside before baking them but I wanted to know if there is a way to make it hollow inside?

Comment: Are you talking about the kind of buns that get steamed?